# jquery real time change from input and select fields

Tags: jquery

Problem with this jquery:

```
$(".aaazzz").live("keyup", function(){

one = $("#amo").attr('value');
two = $("#ame").attr('value');
}
```

`#amo` is input field and `#ame` is select. The problem is that when I change something in `#amo`, it changes in real time but with `select(#ame)` it does not happen. Of course if I change `#ame` and then after change `#amo` it works, but how to get them both working?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7zwCc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".aaazzz" ,function(){
    one = $("#amo").val();
    two = $("#ame").val();
});
```

The code uses [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `.attr()` and will correctly return the select value.

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/rxH8k/

**UPDATE**: If you want the variables to be defined when the keyup event is fired on `.aaazzz` and when `#ame` changes then you could use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/rxH8k/2/

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".aaazzz", function () {
    update();
});

$("#ame").on('change', function(){
    update();
});

function update(){
    one = $("#amo").val();
    two = $("#ame").val();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like problem is that with #ame it do not trigger to refresh jquery, is it possible to refresh it when I select values from dropdown ?

Comment: @MickeyOntegro - I've just updated my answer, it should answer your question.

Comment: Yes, looks like it is solved, I didn't did refresh, and didnt saw your answer before. Thank you !